# Thought experiment in relativistic quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, causality, thought-experiment, locality

### Background

Consider the following thought experiment in the setting of relativistic quantum mechanics (not QFT). I have a particle in superposition of the position basis:

$$ H | \psi \rangle = E | \psi \rangle$$

Now I suddenly turn on an interaction potential $H_{int}$ localized at $r_o = (x_o,y_o,z_o)$ at time $t_o$:

$$
H_{int}(r) = 
\begin{cases} 
      k & r \leq r_r' \\
      0 & r > r' 
   \end{cases}
$$

where $r$ is the radial coordinate and $r'$ is the radius of the interaction of the potential with origin $(x_o,y_o,z_o)$

By the logic of the sudden approximation out state has not had enough time to react. Thus the increase in average energy is:

$$ \langle \Delta E \rangle = 4 \pi k \int_0^{r'} |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2 d r  $$

(assuming radial symmetry).

Now, lets say while the potential is turned on at $t_0$ I also perform a measurement of energy at time $t_1$ outside a region of space with a measuring apparatus at some other region $ (x_1,y_1,z_1)$. Using some geometry it can be shown I choose $t_1 > t_0 + r'/c$ such that:

$$ c^2(t_1 - t_0 - r'/c)^2 -(x_1 - x_0)^2  - (y_1 - y_0)^2 - (z_1 - z_0)^2 < 0 $$

Hence, they are space-like separated. This means  I could have one observer who first sees me turn on the potential $H_{int}$ and measure a bump in energy $\langle \Delta E \rangle $ but I could also have an observer who sees me first measure energy and then turn on the interaction potential.

Obviously the second observer will observe something different.

### Question

How does relativistic quantum mechanics deal with this paradox?

Comment: Your expression for the energy is a global expression, but each observer only has access to local information.

Comment: @kaylimekay I'm not sure what you mean. Both observes will expect causality to hold. The first observer will see him measure $\langle H  + H_{int} \rangle $ on average the other will expect him to measure $\langle H \rangle$ on average. Whose viewpoint is correct?

Comment: Sorry, by "observer" there, I meant you doing the energy measurement. You can only measure the energy in some local patch around you, so you don't actually have access to the global $\langle H\rangle$.

Comment: @kaylimekay In my thought experiment someone else is doing the experiment and then say holds up a sign board with the outcome of the measurement. Neither observer actually does the measurement and both of them have access to the photons reflected of the signboard

Comment: Yeah, the terminology I used in my first comment is inconsistent with what you used in your post so it was confusing. I apologize for that. But my question is, that person doing the measurement experiment, they can only probe the state in their vicinity, which will always look like the unperturbed state for any observer because it is spacelike separated from the perturbation. So won't all observers see that experimenter indicate no perturbation?

Comment: @kaylimekay the state remains unperturbed but the Hamiltonian has changed  and so will the energy eigenvalues and the energy average.

Comment: I have not downvoted, but I think you are not using the sudden approximation correctly.In this link http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/PhysicsProblems/QM/6-Time-dependent%20approximations/sudden.html even a sudden change gives a new  wavefunction . In general any change in boundary condition gives a different solution, and all the actiions you are taking are more and more changes/interactions in my opinion.

Comment: @annav I find your link a bit difficult to follow since its not in latex. In this one ( http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/timedependent.pdf ) they use the comparatively  slow response of the wavefunction (to derive the overlap mentioned in your link) in line $(86)$ Page $21$: "When the Hamiltonian is changed suddenly, the state cannot catch up with the change and basically remains unchanged. This is the basis of the sudden approximation"

Comment: I didn't vote, but my point is that the experimenter cannot measure the global wave function, so they cannot know the things you are suggesting. They can only make local measurements. It's for precisely reasons like this that you have to use QFT. In fact relativistic quantum mechanics *is* QFT.

Comment: @kaylimekay I'm confused what you are going on about. If I measure an energy eigenvalue it is automatically in a superposition of position (as energy and position don't usually commute) so I have automatically measured a property (as you call it) of a global wavefunction. Also there is the study of RQM (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540674573) which is the predecessor of QFT. Yes it is incomplete but I am not aware of it being incomplete for this reason

Comment: The act of measurement itself because of the change of boundary conditions generates a new soluton with new energy levels, each measurement is an interaction, each interaction changes the solutions.

Comment: @annav In standard QM the act of the measurement leaves the average of the wavefunction unchanged. No one takes the Hamiltonian of the interaction of the detector into account.

Comment: This is a basic misconception, in my opinion, : when you measure the emission of a photon from an atom, is the wavefunction unchanged? Is it not the wavefunction of a different energy level?.

Comment: @annav are you talking about the Born rule? Yes the wavefunction does change as per the Born rule but as I said (with a poor choice of words) the average of the observable remains unchanged.

Comment: I am trying to say that "observable"means "interaction", (and usually more than one), and "interaction" changes the wavefunction , and talking of averages of a wavefunction has nothing to do with observation=data which  needs interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any realistic observable is *local*, since any experiment will take place in a finite region of spacetime. One often doesn't need to worry about this in non-relativistic QM, but in relativistic QM (ie, QFT) it is crucial.

Let's denote an observable that takes place at the spacetime point $x$ as $\mathcal{O}(x)$. Then a basic postulate of QFT is that, if $x$ and $y$ are spacelike separated points, for any two observables $\mathcal{O}_1(x)$ and $\mathcal{O}_2(y)$, we have

\begin{equation}
[\mathcal{O}_1(x),\mathcal{O}_2(y)]=0, \ \ \{x,y\}\ {\rm spacelike\ separated}
\end{equation}

In other words, we can simultaneously diagonalize $\mathcal{O}_1(x)$ and $\mathcal{O}_2(y)$. We can expand the whole state into a product of a superposition of $\mathcal{O}_2(y)$ eigenstates, times a superposition of $\mathcal{O}_1(x)$ eigenstates (times superpositions for other spacetime points). Because of this structure, if the superposition over $\mathcal{O}_2(y)$ eigenstates collapses to a single state, this does not mean there is any collapse of the superposition over $\mathcal{O}_1(x)$ eigenstates.

In your example, a sudden change to the Hamiltonian at $y$, will not cause any changes to observables at $x$. Therefore, no local observers will be able to measure changes in the state due to events happening at spacelike separated intervals.

Comment: This is what I tried to say in the comments