# Graduate level introduction for Lieb-Robinson Bounds?

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, many-body, spin-models

I've recently become interested in Lieb-Robinson Bounds [[$1$]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/609401/) [[$2$]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608213/)

Where can I learn more about the Lieb-Robinson Bounds? I am hoping for some graduate level introduction one which builds the tools for even a physicist with little math background to follow?

Comment: Lieb-Robinson bounds are pretty mathematical - both their derivation and their applications. So you would for sure have to learn some mathematical background on the way.

Comment: In that case maybe suggest a mathematical textbook along with one of physics?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point to get an idea in which scenarios Lieb-Robinson bounds can be applied, and what kind of results they allow to prove, could be Hastings' Les Houches notes [Locality in Quantum Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5137).